# How to use private inputs in Cairo1?

Tags: hint, starknet, cairo-lang

I'm trying to write some private protocols(e.g. commitment) in Cairo.

When I pass the private inputs(witnesses) to Cairo through the program input and construct a commitment, I found the private variables go to the public memory which would expose to verifier.

Comment: Are you talking about CairoZero program_input? I'm pretty sure that it doesn't go to the output segment (aka public memory). In any case, in the new language, you don't have the program_input syntax, but there's a nice way to get external hints via [remote rpc calls](https://github.com/reilabs/cairo-hints/blob/main/documentation/Tutorial.md).